# Django : After selecting element from dropdown list, how to perform an action

Tags: python, django

I want to select the option from dropdown list and according to selected element go to my database file which is CSV show the result related to that selected element.

```
my HTML code:
 {% extends "base.html"%}
{%block body%}
{% load static %}
<section>
    <h2 align ="center" margin = 10px>  Selecting parameters </h2>
        <div>
            <form align = 'center' method ="post" action=" help to describe this action url where to direct ?"  >
                {%csrf_token%}

             <label class="label">Generators</label>
             <select id = "myList" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                {% for name in generator %}
               <option> {{name}}</option>
               {%empty%}
               <option> no list found </option>
               {%endfor%}


             </select>

        </div>
    <div>
    <button type="submit" class="myButton"> submit </button>
    </div>
    </form>

  <textarea>{{selected_generator}}</textarea>


</section>


<footer id="main-footer"> <p> Copyright &2019; polito interdispilinary group 2019</p>

</footer>

{%endblock%}

</body>
</html>

Views.py 

def generator(request):

    file = pd.read_csv("G:/interdispilinary project/Website/resources/generator/up_op_zone.csv")
    df = pd.DataFrame(file)
    generator= df['generator']
    operator = df['operator']
    zone = df['zone']
    return render(request, 'generator.html',{'generator':generator})


def gen_results(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        user_submit = gen_form(request.POST)
        print(request.POST)
        if user_submit.is_valid():
            print(user_submit)
            selected_generator = user_submit.cleaned_data['generator']
            request.session['selected_generator'] = selected_generator
        df = pd.read_csv("G:/interdispilinary project/Website/resources/generator/up_op_zone.csv",names=["generator","operator","zone"])
        df1 = df[df["generator"]==selected_generator][["operator","zone"]]
        return render(request, 'generator.html',{'selected_generator':selected_generator})


url.py

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.homepage, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^generator', views.get, name='generator_url'),
    url(r'^gen_results', views.gen_results, name='gen_results_url'),

    url(r'^market', views.market, name='market_url'),
    url(r'^operator', views.operator, name='operator_url'),
```

when i will click to submit button it have to save the result into session and then according to gen_result function it should render the page again

Comment: and what result do you get?

Comment: ValueError at /home/gen_results
The view inter_website.views.gen_results didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: Sounds like it made a GET request rather than POST since `gen_results` only covers the POST path.

Answer (score 0):

`action=" help to describe this action url where to direct ?"`

I think this should be (and probably you were still getting your error when you tried this):

`action="{% url 'gen_results' %}"`

And in your urls.py:

`url(r'^generator', views.get, name='generator_url'),`

should perhaps be pointing to views.generator?

But those probably aren't the cause of your gen_results view returning 'None'.  I would begin to debug whether 'gen_results' ever returns anything.  If render() was failing, or the url mapped to an invalid view, you'd get a different error - this error is that views.gen_results never reaches its 'return' statement:

`if request.method == 'POST':
       # ... as you have it
   else:
       print('actual method=', request.method)`

Best of luck.

## EDIT:  a bit more on forms

(apologies if you already know all about forms)

presumably in forms.py you have something like:

`class GenForm(forms.Form):
    fields = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(index,generator_name)])`

The 'choices' argument wanted a list of 2-tuples; I think you currently just have the names in your template. I'm not sure but I think the first field is intended to represent a primary key or a code, while the second is more of a 'display_name'. It might be easier for you to just do (generator_name, generator_name)

To use the form for both GET and POST your view (generator) should create a gen_form and set the values for its choices:

`generator_list=[(generator,generator) for generator in generators]
gen_form = GenForm(choices=generator_list)`

then pass it to the template:

`return render(request, 'template', {'gen_form':gen_form})`

then rendering it is "simplified" to something like (haven't checked this html, so that submit button might not be quite right, sorry):

```
<form method="post" action="{% url gen_results %}">
{{ csrf_token }}
<p>Please select which generator you're interested in:</p>
{{ gen_form }}
<input type="submit">Submit</input>
</form>
```

---

Alternatively, you can not use the Django forms API anywhere and just grab the submitted generator name from request.POST once you work out what its called (have a poke around in print(request.POST)).  request.POST['generator_name'] should return the string selected if the form or the field had id='generator_name'.

Comment: thanks for understanding the poblem yes i corrected and checked all these errors, but my problem is now with code of gen_results:--->UnboundLocalError at /home/gen_results
local variable 'selected_generator' referenced before assignment

Comment: That suggests that the variable 'selected_generator' is not getting set, which suggests that the 'if user_submit.is_valid():' line is evaluating as false - so your 'gen_form' form is invalid for some reason. Your template doesn't seem to use Django form you use to handle the POST ('gen_form') - maybe the fields the form expects have different names from those you've assigned.  I'll add some stuff to my answer.